# How to re-use check contraint in multiple columns or use relues

Tags: sql-server, constraints, custom-data-type

I want to have percent field in multiple tables. In all of those columns, i would like to validate its value is always between 0 and 100.

For that which one option is better

1. Define individual check constraint to all columns of all tables
2. If we can re-use that contraint how can we?

or

1. define new range rule
2. use of user defined data type called percent and apply that rule

Comment: [`CREATE RULE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-rule-transact-sql): "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work..."

Comment: defining scalar function and using it seems to be good option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably not a "big enough" constraint to bother with reuse...but if you had to, you could define a scalar function and have a check constraint refer to it...like:

```
create function dbo.IsLegalC( @c int ) returns bit as
begin
   return( select case when @c >=0 and @c <=100 then 1 else 0 end )
end

go

create table dbo.t
(
  c 
    smallint not null
    constraint [t.c.check] 
      check( dbo.IsLegalC( c ) = 1 )
)
```

...but this is overkill (and not particularly efficient), when you could just have a `between` expression in the constraint.

Comment: if we use between in direct contraint, in that case, whenever in future our rule/criteria changes, then we need to make change in each and every constrain again,

Comment: Agreed - which is where the function kinda "helps"...but modifying a function that's bound to a table still means you have to force the tables to be rechecked when you alter the function.

Comment: @KoolKabin - but you motivating example is percentages. I haven't checked, but I don't think the definition of percentages has changed... ever.

Comment: If you have to change a constraint on a column - you're in a world of hurt if the existing data isn't compliant - no matter what.

Comment: I probably shouldn't argue against my own answer, but I wouldn't use it unless the constraint is expected to be complex.